# Nodejs RESTful API - PUT 404 (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, rest, put

I'm trying to create a RESTFul API for using Nodejs with MYSQL to create a CRUD web app.
GET and POST seem to be working fine, but when I try to implement an update with PUT,
I get a 404 not found error.

If I use a POST, and have the update sql statement it works fine, but using PUT doesnt seem to work.
This code gives a 404 in the browser ... exact same code, put using router.post instead of put works?

````
router.put('/edit/:id', function(request, response, next){
        var personId = request.body.personId;
        var firstName = request.body.firstName;
        var lastName = request.body.lastName;
            
        var query = `UPDATE person SET firstName = "${firstName}", lastName = "${lastName}" WHERE personId = "${personId }"`;
        
        database.query(query, function(error, data){
        if(error)
        {
            throw error;
            console.log(error);
        }   
        else
        {
            response.redirect("/mypage");
        }

    }); 

    ```
````

Comment: We can't see the code which makes this request, nor can we see your Network tab to see what requests you actually make.

Comment: Maybe you aren't making a PUT request afterall. Maybe you're being redirected to a 404 error. Maybe your PUT request is being cancelled.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Comment: Thanks for comments. Found the answer in the link I commented on